Unable to escape redlock after acquisition has expired
I can't perform any actions after await lock.release(). I suspect it's because the execution time is longer than the lock duration
Node: v12.22.12
  "dependencies": {
    "ioredis": "^5.4.1",
    "redlock": "^5.0.0-beta.2"
  }

const Redis = require('ioredis')
const { default: Redlock } = require('redlock')

const redisUri = 'redis://localhost:6379'

const redis = new Redis(redisUri)
let redlock = null

if (redis) {
    redlock = new Redlock([redis], {
        retryDelay: 1000,
        retryCount: 5 * 60,
    })
}

async function run() {
    const lock = await redlock.acquire(['my-lock'], 1000)
    console.log('Lock acquired');
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))
    console.log('Doing some work');
    await lock.release()
    console.log('Lock released');
}

run()


I want to act as release, even if the execution time is longer than the lock duration
